# How to load data asynchronously UITableview scrolling and core data fetch in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have core data base in my app. In that data base one model CourseEvents contain more then 250000 records, and each record having around 5 fields.

Each records value for one UITableViewCell.

But i don't want to fetch all the records in a single fetch request. want to fetch the some N number of records according to the UITableView scroll.

Example:

When table view load first time want to fetch 20 records, whenever user scroll the UITableView need to fetch next 20 record, like need to fetch the data from model based on the scrolling of the UITableview.

How can i achieve this. kindly help.....

Comment: How is your data sorted?  Is there a predictable distribution to the data? (ie sorted by data and there is one entry every hour?)

Comment: @JonRose thanks for your response.. i am doing like this i concern is when loading tableview it should fetch first 200(for example), when user scroll up and it reach 150 cell then need to fetch next 200 (201-400), if user again scroll down, need to fetch previous 200 (1 - 200). like my fetch should synchronize with UITableView visible cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == arrObject.count-1) {
        if (arrObject.count  < totalDataCount) {
            currentPage++; // initial value is zero
            [self getDataFromResource]; // call api here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... can you send me full code. i want to When table view load first time want to fetch 20 records, whenever user scroll the UITableView need to fetch next 20 record, like need to fetch the data from model based on the scrolling of the UITableview.

Comment: did you get data from api ?

Comment: @KKRocks..YES I got data from API..i want like this..i concern is when loading tableview it should fetch first 200(for example), when user scroll up and it reach 150 cell then need to fetch next 200 (201-400), if user again scroll down, need to fetch previous 200 (1 - 200). like my fetch should synchronize with UITableView visible cell.

Comment: then you need to setup code for pagination in server side . you only need to pass pagenumber .

Comment: my doubt is for example network is not available in device. so device is offline mode. in offline mode i want to fetch data from core data.. so in this scenario how to achieve this thing.please guide me

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this:-
```

//  Using predicate you can fetch 20 records from core data according to scroll.

```
     -(void)viewDidLoad 
        {
           [super viewDidLoad];

         UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
            [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

            minId = 0;
            maxId = 20;
            maxId = minId +maxId;
            NSPredicate*preicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %d && id < %d",minId,maxId];// id is your unique id in core data.
          //  Fetch first 20 records from core data using predicate.
        }

        - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
        {
            float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
            if (bottomEdge >= self.tableView.contentSize.height) //this will get last record of tableview when scroll
                {
                    minId = maxId;
                    maxId = minId + maxId;
                    NSPredicate*preicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %d && id < %d",minId,maxId];// id is your unique id in core data.
                    //  Fetch next 20 records from core data using predicate.
    [self.tableView reloadData];

                }
        }

   // Whenever scroll down ,refresh method is called

    - (void)refreshTable {
      [self.yourArray removeAllobjects];
    minId = 0;
            maxId = 20;
            maxId = minId +maxId;
            NSPredicate*preicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %d && id < %d",minId,maxId];// id is your unique id in core data.
          //  Fetch first 20 records from core data using predicate.

    [self.tableView reloadData]

    }
```

Comment: can you send me full code.. for example i have title and images and core data. i want to when loading tableview it should fetch first 200(for example), when user scroll up and it reach 150 cell then need to fetch next 200 (201-400), if user again scroll down, need to fetch previous 200 (1 - 200). like my fetch should synchronize with UITableView visible cell

Comment: thank you so much.. bro thank you so much..actually i want a small example like display the title and image in uitableviewcell asynchronously using core data.. please send me related code.......

Comment: That is a different issue, you should make a new question about.

Answer (score 0):

@satya murty 
  Try this:-
    uitableviewcell asynchronously using core data.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            cell.tag = indexPath.row;
            //UserRecords TableName
            //self.yourArray records array (fetch from core data)
            UserRecords*records = self.yourArray[indexPath.row];
            if (records)
            {
                cell.imageView.image = nil;
                dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
                dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

                    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:records.imageURL];

                                         UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                                         if (image) {
                                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                 if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
                                                     cell.imageView.image = image;
                                                     [cell setNeedsLayout];
                                                 }
                                             });
                                         }
                });
                cell.textLabel.text = records.title;
            }
return cell;
        }
```

Comment: @satyamurty can you please vote +1 ,if it is work for you.

Comment: thanks for your response. but actually i want like this..for example i have title and images and core data. i want to when loading tableview it should fetch first 200(for example), when user scroll up and it reach 150 cell then need to fetch next 200 (201-400), if user again scroll down, need to fetch previous 200 (1 - 200). like my fetch should synchronize with UITableView visible cell